# Accepting main arguments

Tags: c, random, command-line-arguments

I am writing a random number generator that I wish to take input inside and outside of the program. I am having trouble with main arguments. Here is my code(sorry, it's a little sloppy, but I' only 15)
My problems are in the main function...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int min;
int max;
int howMany;
int in;
int rnd();
void menu();
void getMin();
void getMax();
void getHowMany();
void getNumbers();
void quickRandTut();
void quickRand();
int main(int argc, char **argv[]){
    int i;
    int x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    if(argc > 1){
        for(i = 0; i != argc; i++){
            x = i + 1;
            if(argv[i] == "-min") min = argv[x];
            else if(argv[i] == "-max") max = argv[x];
            else if(argv[i] == "-count") howMany = argv[x];
        }
        quickRand();
    }
    else if(argc == 1) menu();
    return 0;
}
void menu(){
    while(1){
        system("clear");
        printf("[1]Set Min.\n[2]Set Max.\n[3]Set How Many\n[4]Get Numbers\n[5]Quick Rand\n[6]Exit\n\nWhat would you like to do?\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &in);
        if(in == 1) getMin();
        else if(in == 2) getMax();
        else if(in == 3) getHowMany();
        else if(in == 4) getNumbers();
        else if(in == 5) quickRandTut();
        else if(in == 6) exit(0);
    }
}
void getMin(){
    int cont = 0;
    while(cont == 0){
        system("clear");
        printf("What is the smallest number you want?\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &min);
        if(min < 1){
            system("clear");
            printf("Your minimum must be at least 1...\n");
            sleep(3);
        }
        else if(min > 0) cont = 1;
    }
}
void getMax(){
    int cont = 0;
    while(cont == 0){
        system("clear");
        printf("What is the largest number you want?\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &max);
        if(max < 1){
            system("clear");
            printf("Your maximum must be at least 1...\n");
            sleep(3);
        }
        else if(max > 0) cont = 1;
    }
}
void getHowMany(){
    int cont = 0;
    while(cont == 0){
        system("clear");
        printf("How many numbers would you like?\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &howMany);
        if(howMany < 1){
            system("clear");
            printf("You must get at least 1 number...\n");
            sleep(3);
        }
        else if(howMany > 0) cont = 1;
    }
}
void getNumbers(){
    int i;
    int col = 0;
    int num;
    system("clear");
    if(max < min){
        system("clear");
        printf("Your maximum must be larger than you minimum...\n");
        sleep(3);
        menu();
    }
    else if(max > min){
        for(i = 0; i != howMany; i++){
            col++;
            num = rnd(min, max);
            printf("%d. %d\n", col, num);
        }
        printf("\n\n[1]Continue\n>>>");
        scanf("%d", &in);
        menu();
    }
}
int rnd(int min, int max){
    return ((rand() % (max - min)) + min);
}
void quickRandTut(){
    system("clear");
    printf("You can use DSP's Random Number Generator by giving it external arguments.\n");
    printf("You need to give it 3 arguments:\n\t-min #\n\t-max #\n\t-count #\n");
    printf("\nHere is an example input and output:\n\nInput:\n\t/RAND -min 1 -max 10 -count 3\nOutput\n\t1. 3\n\t2. 9\n\t3. 4\n");
    printf("\n-min #, -max #, and -count # arguments must be given in that order.\n\n[1]Menu\n>>>");
    scanf("%d", &in);
    menu();
}

void quickRand(){
    int col;
    int i;
    int num;
    system("clear");
    for(i = 0; i != howMany; i++){  
        num = rnd(min, max);
        printf("%d. %d\n", col, num);
    }
}
```

when I compile it, it tells me this:

```
rand.c: In function ‘main’:
rand.c:23:15: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:23:30: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:24:20: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:24:35: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:25:20: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:25:41: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

When I run it, I give it the following arguments:

```
/RAND -min 1 -max 100 -count 10
```

It doesnt do anything though. Please help in any way you can.

Comment: Try changing char `**argv[]` to `char *argv[]`

Comment: That should be `main(int argc, char *argv[])` only one `*`, not two.

Comment: Could be two `*` without `[]` `main(int argc, char **argv)`

Comment: that only fixes half of the problems. is still says making an intiger from a pointer without a cast

Comment: You can't compare strings like that in C. :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the other answer, change `char **argv` to char `*argv[]`, that solves one thing.

The other errors are there because you treat strings and integers equally. You cannot compare them in C using the `>, <, >=, <=, ==` operators, use the string functions instead (in this case `strncmp()`). The same goes for assignments, you cannot assign a string to an int, you need to convert it, try either `sscanf()`, `atoi()` or any other similar function.

Comment: Most likely neither, as usual ;)

Comment: No wonder his profile has 18 views. All of those who had answered his questions

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `char **argv[]` to char `*argv[]`

And change  `argv[x];` to `*argv[x];` everywhere you are getting error.

That is

```
if(argv[i] == "-min") min = *argv[x];
else if(argv[i] == "-max") max = *argv[x];
else if(argv[i] == "-count") howMany = *argv[x];
```

This is to get rid of the errors

Comment: rand.c In function ‘main’:
rand.c:23:15: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:23:30: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:24:20: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:24:35: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:25:20: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
rand.c:25:41: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: @DarkSun look user3121023's comment.

Comment: @DarkSun My answer will help you get rid off `Syntax Errors` and Kelm's answer will help you get rid off `Logical Errors`

Comment: @BhargavRao we make a great team, don't we?

Comment: @Kelm This is the main essence of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, there are a number of issues here. Cleaning up a few things will help greatly:

Include the header needed for `sleep`:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Fix incomplete prototypes:

```
int rnd(int, int);  /* was an incomplete prototype */
```

`main() is a mess` You need to utilize `atoi` or `strtol` to convert the argument values to numeric values and your loop was unsafe as written. Here are the changes that it appeared to need:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int i;
    // int x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    if(argc > 2){
        for(i = 2; i < argc; i++){
            // x = i + 1;
            if ( strcmp (argv[i - 1], "-min") == 0 ) min = atoi (argv[i]);
            else if (strcmp (argv[i - 1], "-max") == 0 ) max = atoi (argv[i]);
            else if (strcmp (argv[i - 1], "-count") == 0 ) howMany = atoi (argv[i]);
        }
        quickRand();
    }
    else if(argc == 1) menu();
    return 0;
}
```

I have no clue what `col` is supposed to be in `quickRand()`, but you at least need to initialize it to something before you attempt to print it.

With these changes, your code compiles without further warning. Two `rules` will help. **(1)** **Always initialize your variables**, and **(2)** **Always compile with warnings enabled**, (`-Wall -Wextra`) at a minimum. Drop a comment when you hit additional snags.